# can't use SIFT on a numpy array image

Tags: python, opencv, sift

I open a Brain MRI scan:

```
path = os.path.join(r"C:\temp\generated_noisy\patients", 
lst_of_filenames[index_of_filename])
scan = nib.load(path)
data = scan.get_data()
data = data[14:168,18:205,98]
```

so now "data" is a numpy array (the elemnts in it are "numpy.float64"):

```
print(pic.shape)
print(type(pic))
print(type(pic[50,50]))

(154, 187)
<class 'numpy.ndarray'>
<class 'numpy.float64'>
```

Allright, now I try to use SIFT:
    kp,des = sift.detectAndCompute(pic,None)

and I get this error:

```
OpenCV(3.4.2) C:\projects\opencv- 
python\opencv_contrib\modules\xfeatures2d\src\sift.cpp:1121: error: (-5:Bad 
argument) image is empty or has incorrect depth (!=CV_8U) in function 
'cv::xfeatures2d::SIFT_Impl::detectAndCompute'
```

Anyone know how to solve this? I can't seem to find any help online...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SIFT expects the data type to be `uint8`.  However, you won't be able to just convert the array to `uint8` if the values are not in the correct range, such as being greater than 255 or in the range 0-1.  Before converting, you could scale the values so the values are in the range 0-255.  For example, the following will subtract the minimum value so the minimum is zero, then scale so the max is 255.  Then you can convert to type `uint8` without corrupting the image.

```
data = (data - np.min(data)) * 255 / np.max(data)
data = data.astype(np.uint8)
```